# Query to get information from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, wpf, linq, entity-framework, join

I have following tabes in my DB

1. TestPack { id, name, type }
2. InternalWalk { id, tp_id, date }
3. ExternalWalk { id, tp_id, date }
4. Flushing { id, tp_id, date }
5. PunchItems { id, tp_id, name, type, category, reporteddate, closedDate }

tp_Id is the TestPack id and is the foreign key in all other tables which means a TestPack may have 1-N Internal/External Walks, Flushings and PunchItems.

Now I want to query the database (using EF LINQ) to return tests packs, and all their Walks, Flushings, Punchitems against one Test Pack so that I can show all this information in a single DataGrid?

**Test Packs, that dont have ANY Flushings, Walks, PunchItems should not show up in the result. if any of them is present, Test Pack should be displayed in the result**

EDIT:

```
 var queryResult = 
                            from tp in allTestPacks
                            join iwalk in allInternalWalks on tp.id equals iwalk.test_pack_id.Value 
                            into tpIwalk from iwalk in tpIwalk.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            join ewalk in allExternalWalks on tp.id equals ewalk.test_pack_id.Value
                            into tpEwalk from ewalk in tpEwalk.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            join flings in allFlushings on tp.id equals flings.test_pack_id.Value
                            into tpFlings from flings in tpFlings.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            join pitems in allPunchItems on tp.id equals pitems.test_pack_id.Value
                            into tpPitems from pitems in tpPitems.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                                TestPackID = tp.test_pack_no,
                                InternalWalkdDate = iwalk != null ? iwalk.RFIDate : null,
                                ExternalWalkDate = ewalk != null ? ewalk.RFIDate : null,
                                FlushinDate = flings != null ? flings.rfi_no : null,
                                PunchItemCategory = pitems != null ? pitems.description : null//etc
                            };
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Tidied up unnecessary passes

```
var resultset = from tp in allTestPacks
 join iwalk in allInternalWalks on tp.id equals iwalk.test_pack_id.Value into tpIwalk 
 join ewalk in allExternalWalks on tp.id equals ewalk.test_pack_id.Value  into tpEwalk 
 join flings in allFlushings on tp.id equals flings.test_pack_id.Value into tpFlings
 join pitems in allPunchItems on tp.id equals pitems.test_pack_id.Value into tpPitems 

 from iwalk in tpIwalk.DefaultIfEmpty()
 from ewalk in tpEwalk.DefaultIfEmpty()
 from flings in tpFlings.DefaultIfEmpty()
 from pitems in tpPitems.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new
{
 TestPackID = tp.test_pack_no,
 InternalWalkdDate = iwalk != null ? iwalk.RFIDate : null,
 ExternalWalkDate = ewalk != null ? ewalk.RFIDate : null,
 FlushinDate = flings != null ? flings.rfi_no : null,
 PunchItemCategory = pitems != null ? pitems.description : null//etc
};

Console.WriteLine ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery) resultset).ToTraceString();
```

Comment: this is close but not exactly what I need. It brings all those records that have iWalk AND eWalk AND flushings AND pItems. If any of these is missing, the record is not returned. I want the opposite, if any of these is found against a Test Pack, that test Pack and record should be returned, other entries for that record should be empty.

Comment: :) your question states otherwise "Test Packs, that dont have any Flushing, Walks, PunchItems should **not** show up in the result."

Comment: yes, but if any of them is present against a TP, that TP and relevant info should show up :).. sorry for the confusion if thats misleading

Comment: your above code give error that replace = with equals. when done, it says the name 'iscope' is not in scope on the left side of equals. consider swapping the expression with the right side of the equals. after doing this compiler compalins about iwalk, ewalk etc does not exist in the current context. I think passone, passtwo, passthree, passfour needed to be replaced with iwalk, ewalk etc.. once I did this, code compiled but all test packs appeared in the result even those that did not have anything (no flushing, no walks, no punchitems)

Comment: can you send me the code you are using, I am working outside vs, the reason you are seeing all results, because we removed passone, passtwo etc..

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that im using.. if I specifically comment out the PunchItems outer join line like `join into tpPitems from pitems in tpPitems.DefaultIfEmpty()` line in `join pitems in allPunchItems on tp.id equals pitems.test_pack_id.Value
                            into tpPitems from pitems in tpPitems.DefaultIfEmpty()` then I achieve the desired behavior. O

Comment: hi - sorry missed your previous comment. I couldnt use chat due to firewall policy. thats strange when you remove the join on punch items, you get the desired effect,,, did you verify the sql statement that was generated out of EF?

Comment: can you see what gets printed in the console. (please see my edit)

Comment: I tried your updated query, but it returns all the results of the TestPack table regardless of whether Flushings, Walks etc data is there or not. However Console.WriteLine() line throws exception because queryResult is not getting cast to ObjectQuery